# How do I include a local copy of jQuery UI instead of linking to a CDN?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the following references in my index view code,
and I want to download it to my project(to save performance)
when I download them and unzip there is lot of files inside,
which files should I copy to my project and where I should put them
the first one in the content folder and the second in the script folder?

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: 1. That's jQuery UI not jQuery and 2. Just go to the jQuery website.

Comment: @leemo that won't work, you'll be missing the theme's images.

Comment: @Stijn right you are, I was assuming he wanted jquery and didn't think that the link was to ui when writing no. 1

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/ may be able to explain. Generally, you'll want the contents of the `/css/` and `/js/` folders of a [download bundle](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download those two files and include them from your local copy.

Be aware though that in many cases browsers will have the CDN files cached, and will load faster than your local copies.

EDIT: You also need the `images` directory. Just take their bundled download if you need it, then link to the scripts.

Comment: This won't work, as `jquery-ui.css` contains relative paths to images, which also need to be on the local server.

Comment: @pixelistik-so what should I do int this case,leave it as-is?

Comment: @JeanTehhe My advice is not to do it at all. I'm just telling you what to do if you really want to.